# Why's UnicodeDecodeError hidden until after adding time.sleep(1)?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, stderr

**EDITED2:**

In the **EDITED** code below, `f_out.write(bytearray(out or ""))` should be replaced (both times) with:
`f_out.write(bytearray((out or ""), 'utf8'))`  # BEFORE removing  `universal_newlines=True`
OR
`f_out.write(out or "")`# AFTER removing  `universal_newlines=True`

---

**msw, tdelaney, and j-f-sebastian - Thank you so much for all your help!**

**EDITED - As a result, here's the edited version of my script which NOW CONSISTENTLY TRIGGERS UnicodeDecodeError:**

```
#!python3  # Run this script with Python 3.x (in Windows, assuming pylauncher is installed).
import subprocess
import sys

sys.stderr = sys.stdout = open('std.outerr', 'w')
# Redirected stdout/stderr so that they can be seen even when script is not run from command line.
child = subprocess.Popen([r"Evince\bin\Evince.exe", "fuzzed.pdf"], bufsize=0,
                         stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
# `universal_newlines=True` TEMPORARILY left in to show that UnicodeDecodeError is triggered.
# `universal_newlines=True` WILL be removed from FINAL script.
try:
    (out, _) = child.communicate(timeout=5)
# 1 second wasn't long enough for UnicodeDecodeError to consistently be triggered.
# Since subprocess's stderr was redirected to its stdout, 2nd element of tuple will be `None`.
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    child.kill()
    (out, _) = child.communicate()  # Try a 2nd time, without timeout.
    with open('subprocess.out', 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.write(bytearray(out or ""))  # Treat `None` as an empty string).
else:
    print("\nERROR: A crash occurred before the timeout expired!\n")
    with open('subprocess.out', 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.write(bytearray(out or ""))
```

**EDITED - And now (with the script above, minus the `universal_newlines=True`), the 1.2MB, 18,978 line stderr which Evince generated is correctly captured:**

> Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
>   Error: Kid object (page 1) is not an indirect reference (integer)
>
> ....................................................................
>   (Evince.exe:6800): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref:
>   assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

For some [fuzzing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuzzing) I'm doing, the `subprocess.Popen()` call below:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([r"Evince\bin\Evince.exe", "fuzzed.pdf"],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                         universal_newlines=True)
try:
    proc.communicate(timeout=1)  # Works the same with timeout=60 seconds.
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:  # This exception is new to Python 3.3.
    proc.kill()
    # Other code here.
else:
    print("\nERROR: A crash occurred before the timeout expired!\n")
```

gave me a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "p:\python35-64\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()   
File "p:\python35-64\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   
File "p:\python35-64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1279, in _readerthread buffer.append(fh.read())
File "p:\python35-64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 291289:  character maps to [undefined]
```

That occurred even when I simplified the "Other code" to something as simple as `time.sleep(1)`. Yet when I removed the "Other code", no exception occured.

I realize now that the exception occurred because of my unnecessarily specifying `universal_newlines=True` on the `Popen()` call. [That's **not** compatible with a byte being written to `stderr` with a value greater than 127 (which was occcuring).]

However, because the exception only occurs when there's some "Other code" after my `proc.kill()`, it would seem that something else still is likely not quite right with my code. So, I **temporarily** left `universal_newlines=True` in my code, and omitted my "Other code", in order to be better able to determine what that is.

I tried changing `buf_size` and tried `flush()`ing both `stdout` and `stderr, but none of that seems to make any difference.`

I saw in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess) that:

> Popen objects are supported as context managers via the with statement: on exit, 
>   standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited for.

so I tried replacing my `Popen()` call with:

```
with subprocess.Popen(..., universal_newlines=True) as proc:
```

and that generated the `UnicodeDecodeError`, even with no "Other code" present. So, that's 1 way to "fix" my code, but (because of some additional things I need to do), I'd ideally like to use the 3rd-party  `PyPI`[psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/) module. And, regrettably doesn't currently support context managers. So, if possible, I'd like to code this without `with ... as`.

**What else (other than the value of `universal_newlines`) could I change in my code, to "fix" it?**

Based on what the docs said about  "'Popen' objects are supported as context managers", I tried adding:

```
if proc.stdout:
    proc.stdout.close()
if proc.stderr:
    proc.stderr.close()
if proc.stdin:
    proc.stdin.close()
```

and/or `proc.wait()` just before my `proc.kill()`, but then the `proc.kill` was never reached.

What's `with ... as`doing that I should be doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you hit the timeout the background threads are still reading `stdout` and `stderr`. You won't see the error until those threads terminate. As per the docs, _"The child process is not killed if the timeout expires, so in order to cleanup properly a well-behaved application should kill the child process and finish communication:"_ so just add a `proc.communicate()` after the kill. I think that your parent exited before the data was pumped into stderr.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` here?

Comment: **tdelaney:**

Thanks.
 
I missed that addition to the 3.3 docs (where the timeout was added). Sorry about that.
 
But now I'm even more puzzled.
 
I've now made that additon to my script, and if I run the modified script [without time.sleep()] just once, it makes no noticeable difference.
 
But then if I run the script a 2nd (or 3rd or ...) time (without rebooting), then it gets UnicodeDecodeError from the 2nd time on.

Comment: **J.F. Sebastian:**

Wouldn't:
`stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`
send all 3 streams to DEVNULL?

I assume you mean:
`stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`
There's no reason not to use `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.
And since Evince only writes to `stderr`, with it there's no reason not to use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Thanks.

Comment: **J.F. Sebastian:**
Thanks for the insight.
I just searched for  `io.TextIOWrapper` in `subprocess.py` and found:
`if universal_newlines:
self.stdin = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stdin, write_through=True,
line_buffering=(bufsize == 1))`
I had tried adding `bufsize=0` to my .Popen() call, but it made no noticeable difference.
But is that because the `bufsize=1` on `io.TextIOWrapper(self.stdin, write_through=True,
line_buffering=(bufsize == 1))`
is overriding that, making it buffered after all?

Comment: @Russell 1-Use @ syntax if you want me to be notified about your comments 2- you code does not use the output at all. DEVNULL is the proper way to discard the output 3- there are multiple buffers: in the child process, in the parent, OS pipe buffers, TextIOWrapper might use auxiliary buffers for decoding and/or finding end-of-line  —you can't disable them. 4- if all you need is to save the output to a file then set `stdout=open('subprocess.out', 'wb',0)` (use `check_call()` instead of `Popen().comminicate()`) though it is a separate question 5- unrelated: your bytearray usage is incorrect.

Comment: 1. Right. Thanks.

2. Evince only writes to stderr, but something else to be fuzz-tested may write to stdout. That's why I'm saving both to the same PIPE, and getting that as the 1st element of communicate()'s returned tuple.

3. I hadn't realized that. Thanks.

Comment: 4. I'm fuzz-testing several PDF readers most of which (unlike Evince) rarely write to stdout/stderr. So, although I didn't show this in my simplified, posted code, I only save non-empty stdout/stderr to a file. 
[Why create potentially 1000s of empty files?] So, I need a PIPE, and  the docs for check_call() say: "Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from." Also, when there's no crash, I need to do Popen.kill() to terminate the child process.

Comment: 5. Good catch. AFTER I've removed the `universal_newlines=True`,
`f_out.write(bytearray(out or ""))` works. (Although all that's needed then is `f_out.write(out or "")`.
But BEFORE removing it, I do need `f_out.write(bytearray((out or ""), 'utf8'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output may be buffered and therefore the text can be decoded even after the child process is already dead. If there is no `time.sleep(1)` then the parent might exit before the decoding has encountered the error (I/O reader daemon threads started by `.communicate()` are killed then the parent process exits).

Comment: I took the combined help of all of the comments and answers (including the 1 by msw which has since been deleted) AND increased the `timeout` on my `communicate(timeout=sec)`to 5 seconds. As a result, my script (before my final removal of `universal_newlines=True`) was able to consistently generate the UnicodeDecodeError. Without the  `universal_newlines=True`, my code now correctly captures Evince's `stderr`. Thank you.